# SUBMIT parameters values when not defined?

Tags: abap

When you comment a parameter in a `SUBMIT` of a report, what would be its value? The initial value of that type or the value that should have in a standard run of the equivalent transaction?

I mean, if you want to run a transaction setting in a defined way several dynprofields by submitting the transaction report, would you have to state every field that does have initial value or set just those that differ from the usual value they have when executing the transaction?

Comment: Additionally to Jozsef's answer, remember that in the submitted report may be defined [default values](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_731_index_htm/7.31/en-US/abapparameters_value.htm#!ABAP_ADDITION_1@1@). If those defaulted parameters are not provided with `SUBMIT`, they are autopopulated by those values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial value, so you don't need to pass those values in the SUBMIT (you can comment those out).